# Using javascript (.js) in Google App Engine

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine

Using GAE, I am trying to call a text fade function from a separate .js file.

The template and styling are both visible when running the app locally, but the JavaScript code will not run.

Funny thing is: The HTML doc with styling and JS works fine when run in browser separately.

**main.py:**

```
import webapp2
import jinja2

from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

import os
import urllib

JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
    extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'],
    autoescape=True)

template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('/templates/Fade.html')

class MainHandler(BaseHandler):

    def get(self):
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
        self.response.write(template.render())

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),
    ('/login', LoginHandler),
    ('/logout', LogoutHandler),
    ("/(?:[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/?)", PageHandler),
    ('/signup', SignupHandler)
], debug=True)
```

**Fade.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome!</title>

<style type="text/css">     
    div.box1{
        position:absolute;
        top:30%;
        left:35%;
    }

    div.box2{
        position:absolute;
        top:45%;
        left:40%;
    }
</style>

<script type = "text/javascript" src="D:\Program\Google\Appengine Apps\myExample\static\js\Fade.js"></script>

</head>

<body onload="fadeDivs('div1', 'div2')">

<div id="div1" class="box1">text1</div>
<div id="div2" class="box2">text2</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Fade.js**

```
var fade_in_from = 0;
var fade_out_from = 10;

function fadeIn(div){

var target = document.getElementById(div);
target.style.display = "block";
var newSetting = fade_in_from / 50;
target.style.opacity = newSetting;
fade_in_from++;

if(fade_in_from == 50){
    target.style.opacity = 1;
    clearTimeout(loopTimer);
    fade_in_from = 0;
    return false;
}


var loopTimer = setTimeout('fadeIn(\''+div+'\')',30);
}

function setOpacity(div){
target = document.getElementById(div);
target.style.opacity = 0;
}

function fadeDivs(div1, div2){
setOpacity(div1);
setOpacity(div2);

fadeIn(div1);
var time = setTimeout('fadeIn(\''+div2+'\')', 1500);
}
```

**app.yaml:**

```
application: myExample
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /static/
  static_dir: static

- url: /js
  static_dir: static/js

- url: /images/thumbnails
  static_dir: static/images/thumbnails

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
- name: jinja2
  version: "2.6"
```

Comment: Did you use chrome to debug your client code? https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: @voscausa Debug mode revealed that the app couldn't access the script. seemes like I have it working now though.

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src="D:\Program\Google\Appengine Apps\myExample\static\js\Fade.js"></script>
```

This will not work in production as this is a local path related to your computer. You need to put something as `src="static/js/Fade.js"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for spotting that! :) Also removing the js handler in app.yaml seems to have done the trick.