# How do I load my external javascript file into my index.html file

Tags: javascript, html, google-app-engine

Trying to externally load my javascript file into my main html file. Script works fine when I load it internally.

index.html file below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> -->
    <link href="./static/css/index.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="../scripts/index.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
</head>

 <body>
    <input type="text" id="myInput" class="carrierinput" onkeyup="myCarriers()" placeholder="   Search for LTL Carriers...">
        <ul id="myUL">
            <li><button type="button" class="collapsible">Central Transport</button>
                <div class="content">
                </div> 
            </li>
        </ul>
   </body>
</html>
```

index.js file below:

```
function myCarriers() {
     // code here
}
```

project directory below:

[image]

Comment: Is the site deployed with that directory structure? That looks like a pre-compilation arrangement. What templating engine are you using?

Comment: I am not sure what a templating engine is but I am deploying the app through Google Cloud App Engine. I currently have all my css files in a 'static' folder in the directory and they are able to be loaded into my html files just fine. Is there a difference between <link> and <script>?

Comment: That seems like critical information. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22477218/using-javascript-js-in-google-app-engine and related posts.

Comment: Ah yes, I had to put my 'scripts' folder under the 'Static' directory. I believe its regarding how app engine compiles the project when deployed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your html file seems to exist inside the templates directory, which means you have to go up one dir for the script first

```
<script src="../scripts/index.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
```

You also seem to be missing a '>' for the closing body

Answer (score 0):

**When you want to import a file in the same directory, you import it as follows:**

```
"./FILE_NAME"
```

**When you want to import a file in an inner directory:**

```
"./INNER_DIRECTORY_NAME/FILE_NAME"
```

**When you want to import a file in a parent directory:**

```
"../FILE_NAME"
```

**So here are the combinations:**

- `./` current directory
- `../` parent directory

So in order to import your JavaScript file, simply, refer to the parent directory:

```html
<script src="../scripts/index.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
```

---

When a file name is *index*, ex: *index.html*, *index.js*, you can leave the file name and only mention the directory name, ex, in your case:

```html
<script src="../scripts" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To link your index.js file. You have to first go outside from your current directory (which is templates, because you are writing this in the templates directory)

For that, you have to type `../`

Then you are outside of the template directory.

Then you have to go to the scripts directory,
you can do like this `../scripts`

Eventually, you want to approach the correct file in that scripts folder, for that `../scripts/index.js`|

So simply change your,

`./scripts/index.js` to `../scripts/index.js`

wanna learn more about relative paths, watch this: https://youtu.be/hxto_sRZsBg